# Can I convert 12 V DC to 24 V DC using a 2N2222A?

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, dc

I have a circuit which generates a 12 V DC high pulse when a laser is detected. I want to convert this high pulse to 24 V DC to feed into a PLC input (Siemens S7-1200.) Can I do this using a 2N2222A?

Comment: Do you already have a 24V rail available?

Comment: You need a step-up converter. Which theoretically could contain your specific transistor, but it probably would make no sense to use that transistor.

Comment: Is there a requirement on the rise time of the pulse, or how long between the laser pulse being detected and the PLC taking action?

Comment: This PLC also has analogue inputs which will withstand 30V: if your pulses are long enough, you could consider using one of these without intervening circuit (or just a resistor divider pair);

Comment: Yes i have 24v rail available @vir

Comment: @ChesterGillon There is no such requirement

Answer (score 3):

If you can accept inverted logic into your PLC, this would do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3JwUP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you can't have inverted logic, use two:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb4Sq4.png)</sup>

You need to check all resistor values.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yes. I just threw in resistor values at close to random. Especially the first inverter stage could be far higher resistances.

Answer (score 1):

S7-1200 has [IEC Type 1 sink inputs](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/465/36932465/att_106119/v1/s71200_system_manual_en-US_en-US.pdf) so you need to provide current of nominal 4 mA 24 V at the input (minimum 15 V).

[image]

One way to do that is with two transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLMA2s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alternatively a single transistor with a 1 kΩ 1 W load resistor (below circuit) will provide more than the minimum 15 V input required, at the cost of some noise immunity and inverting the signal.